# Jquery split function not working on setting numeric option value

Tags: jquery, split

I am trying to use jquery split function to set the option value but it is not working. I must be missing something really simple (new to programming!).

```
$("#product").on('change keyup', function() {
var value = $('option:selected', this).text();
$("#small").val(value.split('-')[1]);
$("#medium").val(value.split('-')[2]);
$("#large").val(value.split('-')[3]);
}).keyup();​

<select id="product">
    <option value="ronald mcdonald-100-200-300">ronald</option>
    <option value="the hamburglar-150-250-350">ronald</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="0" id="small">Small</option>
    <option value="0" id="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="0" id="large">Large</option>
</select>
```

​Also on jsfiddle for your viewing pleasure: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6tPEJ/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var value = $('option:selected', this).attr('value'); // not .text(), if you use text
                                                      // it will give you ronald as return
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FQSPy/2/)**

or

```
var value = $(this).val(); // also return you the selected option value
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FQSPy/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6tPEJ/7/)**

Replace

```
var value = $('option:selected', this).text();
```

with

```
var value = $('option:selected', this).val();
```